# With isn't the margin of the following :after affecting the next element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add margin to an `span` element using `:after`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.title-border {
  width: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  background: rgb(102, 46, 145);
  &:after {
    display: inline-block margin: 0 8px content: ''
  }
}

.horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="title-border">
      <span class="horizontal">
        Some text
      </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

However, there's no margin at all (there should be a space between the purple border and the text):

[image]

Why is this and how to fix it?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/JOepyM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

use

```
.title-border ::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  content: 'try this';
}
```

instead of

```
  &:after {
    display: inline-block margin: 0 8px content: ''
  }
```

add `margin: 0px 10px;` in `.title-border`

```css
.container {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.title-border {
  width: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  margin: 0px 10px;
  background: rgb(102, 46, 145);
}

.title-border::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
}

.horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="title-border"></span>
  <span class="horizontal">
     Some text
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: There's still no padding or margin in your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Give some padding : .horizontal { padding-left: 10px;}

```css
.container {
   display: flex !important;
   justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.title-border {
  width: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  background: rgb(102, 46, 145);
  &:after {
    display: inline-block
    margin: 0 8px
    content: ''
  }
}

.horizontal {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="title-border">
  <span class="horizontal">
    Some text
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add padding-left in '.horizontal' class

```
.container {
     display: flex !important;
     justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.title-border {
    width: 3px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '';
    background: rgb(102, 46, 145);
}

.horizontal {
    padding-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```